# How does one get Firefox media playing on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, firefox, video, ffmpeg

I have a brand new Ubuntu 20.04 running on my new computer.  YouTube videos play without a glitch, but no other audio/video can play.  H/W accelerator is off.  When I try to install ffmpeg, I end up with a terminal that shows the following.  One cannot access the OK to get past this point.  [image: Terminal]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you tried to install `ffmpeg` via command-line, in this case you'd have to use Tabulator-Key (the one two below Esc) to highlight the "OK"-Button and press Enter.

Besides `ffmpeg` I usally also install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Answer (score 0):

MY BAD!  What a dummy.  I forgot you can get to the OK by hitting TAB.  I'm sooo sorry.  Insufficient morning caffeine.